# Marketing cloud content builder - possible to change tab name when opening mail in browser?

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, email-template, url, content-builder

As the title says - in content builder, is it possible to change the name of the browser tab when opening a mail in browser? Right now the browser tab gets an automatic generated link that looks like this `http://view.s7.exacttarget.com/...randomtokens...`

Right now the code in contentbuilder looks like this in the HTML-tab but what do i need to add? Is it possible to change the title?

```
To view this email as a web page, click <a href="%%view_email_url%%">here.</a>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the change the "Title" element in the head section of your email/template code to change what's shown on the browser tab...

```
<head>
  <title>What I Want to Show On The Tab Title</title>
</head>

<body>
The content of the email......
</body>

</html>
```

Also take a look at [Icons](https://www.w3.org/2005/10/howto-favicon), if you want something more branded. The View as a Web Page link opens your email as a web page much like any other web page.

Comment: The value of the title could be an AMPScript variable, BTW.

Comment: Thanks, i will try this solution and accept answer if it works!

Answer (score 1):

The link `To view this email as a web page, click <a href="%%view_email_url%%">here.</a>` is a standard personalization link in marketing cloud which gets appended if you're creating an email based on a standard template. 
If you want to introduce a personal web page, I would suggest to create a cloud page and pass the necessary parameters and use AMP Script to create the same information as per Email body.
In case you are using sub-domains for cloud pages, you can get a branded URL.
If you are using URL expiration, check out the [March Release](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/release_notes/march_2017_release/)